# R function for adjusting for stock splits and dividend

Tags: r

I am trying to write a function in R that adjusts for stock splits and dividend. I have about 150 stocks downloaded independently(not from yahoo). I have the close price and dividends data but want to calculate the adjusted price.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

`TTR::adjRatios` will calculate the adjustment ratios for you.  `quantmod::adjustOHLC` is an example of how to use it.  Just substitute your data in place of the calls to `getDividends` and `getSplits`.

Comment: Thank you,I was not sure where I would use the TTR::adjRatios function to calculate the adjustment ratio vector but I understand now.